# UnknownPluginException using Google Play Services and Plugins DSL

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm creating a new application in Android Studio Bumblebee and this defaults to using the new Groovy DSL plugin management in `settings.gradle`.

I need to be able to use Google Play Services to enable Firebase functionality, however I am running into a build error when applying the `com.google.gms.google-play-services` plugin using the documentation here: [Google Play Services Readme](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/master/google-services-plugin)

I have added the following to my `settings.gradle` file:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0-alpha13'
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0-alpha13'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10'
    }
}
```

and the following to my app's `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

however when I build the application, I get the following `UnknownPluginException`:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.10'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.10'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.3.10')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
```

I have also tried the legacy method of `classpath` etc. but this results in a much longer error message regarding dependency resolution.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the `google-services` plugin to the `plugins {}` block is causing errors. The alternate way that I've found is:

1. First, in your root build file (not the one in the app folder), inside the `buildscript {}` block, add this

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
   google()
   mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
 }
}
```

2. In the build file in the app folder, apply the plugin like this,

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In step 1, using `mavenCentral()` is necessary as the `google-services` plugin downloads the linked dependencies like `gson` from maven central :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JustinCoding. I was under the impression that in order for Firebase to work it needs to be a plugin. Will adding it as an `implementation` allow Firebase to work the same?

Comment: Hey, I've edited the answer to suit your needs better, please update the same in your project. And, this method works like a plugin only :D

Comment: Looks like this worked :) - It threw up loads of issues last time about dependencies not being resolved, however it seems to have worked itself out with the inclusion of `mavenCentral()`. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome mate! Please mark this answer as accepted, so it may help others :)

Answer (score 4):

By using Android Studio Bumblebee new Groovy DSL plugin management Add below line in build.gradle(Project:) plugins{} section and sync project will solve your problem.

```
id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false
```

your build.gradle(Project:) looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.8.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

your build.gradle(Module:) looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            enableV3Signing true
            enableV4Signing true
        }
    }
}
```

your settings.gradle(Project Settings) looks like

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MyApp"
include ':app'
```